# Searching for terms in a set of files

Tags: files, search

I have two files:

```
files_to_search.out
terms_to_search.out
```

I'd like to create a command that identifies terms in `terms_to_search.out` that are not used in any of the files in `files_to_search.out`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky if you want to account for terms that can overlap, e.g. a single line containing `banana` is enough to count as a use of both `ban` and `nan`.

Here's a minimally-tested, quick-and-dirty perl script. It reads the strings to search (the needles) and the file names, then builds a regular expression that matches any of the needles. When it finds a match, it removes the matched string from the set of needles and rebuilds the regex. The needles that are left over at the end are the ones you're after.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
open FILENAMES, "<", "files_to_search.out" or die $!;
@filenames = <FILENAMES>;
close FILENAMES;
chomp foreach @filenames;
open NEEDLES, "<", "terms_to_search.out" or die $!;
@needles = <NEEDLES>;
close NEEDLES;
chomp foreach @needles;
%needles = map {$_, 1} @needles;
sub build_re {
    $re = qr/(@{[join("|", map quotemeta, keys %needles)]})/;
}
@ARGV = @filenames;
while (<ARGV>) {
    while (/$re/) {
        delete $needles{$1};
        exit if !%needles;
        build_re();
    }
}
print map "$_\n", sort keys %needles;
```

Answer (score 2):

quick ugly attempt at a one liner (with GNU grep for the `-o` option):

```
grep -of terms_to_search_out $(cat files_to_search.out | tr '\n' ' ') | sort | uniq | grep  -vf terms_to_search_out
```

Comment: Note that all of `\n`, `\t` and space are used by default to split command substitutions, so there's no point changing `'\n'` to `' '`. Restricting IFS to newline and do the reverse conversion would even make more sense since newline characters are less likely to occur in file names than space characters. Also note that filename generation is also performed (except in zsh) upon command substitution so blank characters in filenames are not the only problematic ones (see `set -f` to disable filename generation).

Comment: learn something new everyday - wasn't aware about the `\n` defaults. So maybe pass through sed to add quotes? or go with a for loop?