# Searching for terms that occur exactly once in a set of files

Tags: grep

Similar to this question: [Searching for terms in a set of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/searching-for-terms-in-a-set-of-files), only I expect each term to occur at least once in the set of files. How can I modify the search so that I can get a subset of the list of terms that occur exactly once in the set of files?

Answer (score 6):

`sort | uniq -c | grep 1` won't work correctly if the files contain 1s

Instead, we should use the uniq option -u, which only prints unique lines:

`sort | uniq -u`

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out: `sort | uniq -c | grep 1`

Comment: So, are you saying that your words always appear on a line by themselves (i.e., not in sentences)?   [The question that you linked to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55146/80216 "Searching for terms in a set of files") doesn’t include that stipulation.   If you have a condition like that,  it’s useful to mention it in your question.